# Alert saying it's blocked when I try to open a URL that isn't allowed

Tags: swift, uikit

I actually tried to add if-else statement in the showPage func, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
func openPage(action : UIAlertAction){
    if  let url = URL(string: "http://" + action.title!) {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }else{
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Valid URL", message: "wrong url", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel))
        present(ac , animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is `action.title` value when it fails?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: to help you in next step :) Even if the URL creation works fine, webview might not be able to load the page as you are trying to open a URL with http, and transport security will block HTTP requests, unless you have enabled allow arbitrary loads for whatever domain you are trying to access :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in your code.

1. It's not possible to declare a variable in the " if " statement.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://" + action.title!);

if (URL) {
    //do something...
}
```

2. Class constructor URL cannot be invoked without 'new'.

```
let url = new URL(string: "http://" + action.title!);
```

3. It's better to put all of your codes in a try-catch block.

```
function openPage(action: UIAlertAction) {
    try {
        //do something...
    } catch (e) {
        //handle error...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a Swift question. The init method is `convenience init?(string URLString: String)`, it's an optional. So yes, you can "create variable in a if test", that's soft unwrapping. How can this question be validate? What's @Peter real code?